# I am having trouble locating an issue with my xml files how do I locate a Bad signature (0x01549FF9) at position 0x001D4DA8

Tags: xlsx, epplus

While attempting to troubleshoot a use case I get a "Bad signature (0x01549FF9) at position  0x001D4DA8" exception after trying to open the workbook. What is the best way to find what part of the xlsx xml is causing this issue?

Opening the file in Excel and saving it resolves the issue and I can see from diffs that Excel must have found and corrected "errors" but there are too many to definitively figure out which one is the issue.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void FileSaving_FileOpensAfterMultipleEdits_FunctioningFile()
    {
        var template = @"C:\xxxxx\test.xlsx";
        var outputSmokeTest = Path.Combine(testDocumentsRootDirectory, @"Results\CorruptTest.xlsx");
        smokeTestWorkbook = new Workbook(key);
        if (File.Exists(outputSmokeTest))
            File.Delete(outputSmokeTest);
        smokeTestWorkbook.Open(template);

        smokeTestWorkbook.SaveAs(outputSmokeTest);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a reference to the workbook
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void Open(string workbookPath)
    {            
        var loggerString = "Open";
        if (File.Exists(workbookPath))
        {
            try
            {
                logger.Track(loggerString);
                excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(workbookPath));         
            }              
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.TrackException(loggerString, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

the new ExcelPackage line is what causes the exception.

Comment: That error sounds like a zip file issue which is what XLSX uses as its container.  Try to rename the file to `.zip` and see if it opens in 7-zip or something similar.  Also, confirm that it is not an XLS that has been renamed to XLSX.  Excel will detect that and correct but it usual gives a warning.  Epplus does not support XLS.

Comment: I am not sure but _if_ it is a zipped file and _if_ it contains one or more xml files, you should be able to extract the xml file(s) and have it checked for consistency.

Comment: Correct I can get to the xml but there is nothing wrong the files to my eye (obviously not reliable) and even barring that there is an application (Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office) that has cleared these files with "no validation error is found in the package" which I would expect to find issues if there were any.

Comment: Interesting the OpenXML is ok with it.  Only thing I can recommend at this point is to download the EPPlus source code and pull it into your project.  See if you can debug it.  Could be a bug that the devs need to know about.